# rmarkdown ioslides: output file in a folder and dependencies in other

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to embbed an ioslides rmarkdown presentation in a jekyll website, so I need to `render` the `.Rmd` file to a `_posts` folder in the main directory of my website.

But, images can't be placed in this folder, so I'm placing then in a `images` folder.

My problem is that when I `render` my `.Rmd` all dependencies are placed in the same folder as the output file.

I tried to use the `self_contained: false` and then pass the following arguments to `knitr`, but this didn't work.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "/images/")
```

Comment: do you have permission to create and write in the `/images/` folder from where the `render` is run?

Comment: @Daniel, have a look at this post that I have answered. I think this will help you in what you need as it is in a similar train of thought as your question:[Output dependencies through a script to a specific folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047164/when-using-servrjekyll-on-r-where-should-i-save-my-rmd-files/35048414#35048414)

Comment: i'm using something like this in my site, but it doesn't work for ioslides presentations :(

Comment: I do not know why it does not work for you, but see how I apply this: [code](https://github.com/setempler/setempler.github.io/blob/master/Makefile) and [details](http://setempler.github.io/blog/2016-03-24/using-rmd-with-jekyll)

Comment: I think the problem is something in ioslides. When using in raw Rmd this works ok

Answer (score 0):

`fig.path` indicates a folder relative to the project folder. In your case you have to use `base.dir` to set an absolute folder:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(base.dir = "/images/")
```

Comment: this doesn't work :( rmarkdown keeps creating a folder called `filename_files` to store the created images.

Comment: For me it works, but I use `fig.path` with `"images/"` instead `"/images/"`. See also the [code](https://github.com/setempler/setempler.github.io/blob/master/Makefile) and [details](http://setempler.github.io/blog/2016-03-24/using-rmd-with-jekyll).