# When using servr::jekyll() on R, where should I save my Rmd files?

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr

With the Rmd files on root (eg. on my /knitr-jekyll/) they are turning into md files, but not on html files. Thus, they appear as simple markdown text.
I tried to put them on /_source and on /_posts but it get's worse, in this case I also don't get the md files.

Answer (score 2):

I found creating a separate folder all together solves the problem.

```
/kintr-jekyll/_rmd/test.Rmd
```

But do remember that when you knit your `Rmd` to `md` that you knit to the `_post` folder if you using the standard bootstrap template. Also make sure that you specified your figure output. Easiest is to write some function which does this for you:

```
KnitPost <- function(input, base.url = "/") {
  require(knitr)
  opts_knit$set(base.url = base.url)
  fig.path <- paste0("figures/", sub(".Rmd$", "", basename(input)), "/")
  opts_chunk$set(fig.path = fig.path)
  opts_chunk$set(fig.cap = "center")
  render_jekyll()
  knit(input, envir = parent.frame())
```

Lastly, go make sure in your `.md` file in `knitr-jekyll/_post` that the figures are clearly referenced. This should be within your `test.md`:

```
<img align="middle" src="/figures/test/test_image.jpg">
```

This link might help: [R-Bloggers post about jekyll](http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-jekyll-blog-posts-from-r/)

Comment: See also this [example](https://github.com/setempler/setempler.github.io) explained in this [blog post](http://setempler.github.io/blog/2016-03-24/using-rmd-with-jekyll) using the explained `KnitPost` method. All files remain in the same folder (`Rmd` and `md`), figures go to subfolders of `image/`.